# Use Case Diagram Option and Option AND two actor in one module same use case

Tags: uml, use-case

The case 1:
The Human Resource Manager can add a new employee. HR Manager can either add the admin staff or add academic staff. And Academic staff has full-time or part-time. I know that the primary use case is add a new employee. But the Question is did I `<<include>>` a use case which is "select the category of staff" after "add a new employee"  ?

[image]

The Case 2:
The student and admin both can view, edit the student profile. But additionally admin can delete the certain info about student. So did i draw is TRUE?

[image]

Comment: This is a test, isn't it? Looks like "complete the drawings"...

Comment: Are you mocking us with these child drawings? Please use a proper UML tool and draw some readable diagram and then come back here.

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly stated, the UC in the first case is `Add employee`. Full/part time are attributes you assign to an employee object. This is part of the story (activities) you describe within the use case. These steps are not use cases. Don't fall in the trap to start functional decomposition.

The 2nd case would be ok this way. However, you can go different ways:

[image: ![enter image description here]

If `Admin` inherits from `Student` this actor has the same use cases (so `Admin` is associated with all the UCs).

Another way is

[image]

where you have a general editor and you add constraints for accessing use cases.

There are reasons for using each of the above which vary by different domains.